Is there a way to return the highest value in Excel?
The Problem
I'm working directly on a Excel sheet with the Python extension for Excel and I'm trying to find out which is the highest number of a list of cells.
This is the code for the function that I wrote:
def getMax(celle_voti_lista) -> int:
    valori = [v for v in celle_voti_lista if isinstance(v, (int, float))]
    return max(valori) if valori else 0

And this is the function call:
max(xl("D11:D23"))

But everytime I run this code, It gives me 0 instead of the actual highest number.
What should I do?

try something like this:
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def xl(range_str, file_path, sheet_name):
    wb = load_workbook(file_path)
    sheet = wb[sheet_name]
    start_cell, end_cell = range_str.split(":")
    start_row, start_col = int(start_cell[1:]), start_cell[0].upper()
    end_row, end_col = int(end_cell[1:]), end_cell[0].upper()
    cells = []

    for row in sheet[f"{start_col}{start_row}":f"{end_col}{end_row}"]:
        for cell in row:
            cells.append(cell.value)
    return cells

def getMax(celle_voti_lista) -> int:
    valori = [v for v in celle_voti_lista if isinstance(v, (int, float))]
    return max(valori) if valori else 0

and then:
file_path = "data.xlsx"
sheet_name = "Sheet1"
max_value = getMax(xl("D11:D23", file_path, sheet_name))
print(max_value)


Thank but what I'm using is the add-in for Excel which allows to add Python code. This is the website. If there's a way to solve it it would be perfect, instead I use some VBA code.
